# Common Practice for Unary Operators

Tags: python, operators

In Python, what is the common or accepted way to apply the unary operators? I know the usual way for handling operators in expressions includes inserting spaces between the operators and the variables (`a = b + c`), but inserting a space between a unary operator and a variable doesn't look as neat in my opinion.

```
# Should we use
a = -a
a = +a
a = ~a

# or
a = - a
a = + a
a = ~ a
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, do what ever you prefer.  First way is more common.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) gives a general style guide for python. It suggests adding spaces around operators with lower precedence, e.g. Yes: `x = x*2 - 1`, No: `x = x * 2 - 1` given unary operators tend to have a very high precedence then I would suggest the style guide suggests no space but this is a matter of taste. My taste is definitely the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) describes that higher precedence operators should have no separation between them ie:

```
a = -a
a = +a
```

and other operators like these should have this spacing.